# Allow user enter $ sign in front of number?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I had the following model property

```
    [DisplayName("Salary per year")]
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
```

And the rasor markup is

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salary)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salary)
```

The generated html code:

```
<input class="text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Salary per year must be a number." data-val-required="The Salary per year field is required." id="Salary" name="Salary" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Salary" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="Salary" class="" style="">The field Salary per year must be a number.</span></span>
```

The client validation only allow user enters numbers. However, user want to be able to enter $ in front of the number (I wonder later they want to be able to enter "," to separate the digitals too). How to enable it? (and parse the string to `decimal` in the controller?)

Right now it shows "The field Salary per year must be a number." in red as soon as I typed "$".

Comment: check the code samples from the answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1)create a function for keypress and make sure the key press key code is a number or comma:

a) this might be a library to use: http://jquerypriceformat.com/

```
$('#example1').priceFormat();
```

b) create custom code for this:

```
$('#example1').on("keypress", function (e){
if( event.keyCode == ',' ||  event.keyCode == '$' || (event.keyCode => '0' &&  event.keyCode <= '9'))          {
    // allow char
} else {
e.preventDefault();
}

});
```

c) this example works best:

http://help.dottoro.com/ljlwfxum.php

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function FilterInput (event) {
            var chCode = ('charCode' in event) ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;

                // returns false if a numeric character has been entered
            return (chCode < 48 /* '0' */ || chCode > 57 /* '9' */);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    The following text field does not accept numeric input:
    <input type="text" onkeypress="return FilterInput (event)" />
</body>
```

2)when you submit form you should parse the value from the input and remove the $ char.

```
var val = $('#example1').val();
val = val.slice(2);
```

Comment: Right now it shows "The field Salary per year must be a number." as soon as I typed "$".

Comment: I think $ should not be typed by user, just type a number

Comment: I told the users there is no need to type $, but they insist they should be able to type $ following numbers

Comment: then there is only b) option for you.

Comment: Will it allow users type "324$$123.$2"? BTW, what's 'char for 0'?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27222/discussion-between-floradu88-and-nickw)